# How to arrange string in kotlin by the numbers?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have string with text and numbers like this for example

`var text = "1 Hello world 2 how are you 3 im fine here"`

How i can make it start new line by every number?? Like this

```
1 Hello world
2 how are you
3 I'm fine
```

And That is the text `var my_text = "1 فِي الْبَدْءِ خَلَقَ اللهُ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالأَرْضَ. 
2 وَكَانَتِ الأَرْضُ خَرِبَةً وَخَالِيَةً، وَعَلَى وَجْهِ الْغَمْرِ ظُلْمَةٌ، وَرُوحُ اللهِ يَرِفُّ عَلَى وَجْهِ الْمِيَاهِ. 
3 وَقَالَ اللهُ: «لِيَكُنْ نُورٌ»، فَكَانَ نُورٌ. 
4 وَرَأَى اللهُ النُّورَ أَنَّهُ حَسَنٌ. وَفَصَلَ اللهُ بَيْنَ النُّورِ وَالظُّلْمَةِ. 
5 وَدَعَا اللهُ النُّورَ نَهَارًا، وَالظُّلْمَةُ دَعَاهَا لَيْلاً. وَكَانَ مَسَاءٌ وَكَانَ صَبَاحٌ يَوْمًا وَاحِدًا.
6 وَقَالَ اللهُ: «لِيَكُنْ جَلَدٌ فِي وَسَطِ الْمِيَاهِ. وَلْيَكُنْ فَاصِلاً بَيْنَ مِيَاهٍ وَمِيَاهٍ». 
7 فَعَمِلَ اللهُ الْجَلَدَ، وَفَصَلَ بَيْنَ الْمِيَاهِ الَّتِي تَحْتَ الْجَلَدِ وَالْمِيَاهِ الَّتِي فَوْقَ الْجَلَدِ. وَكَانَ كَذلِكَ. 
8 وَدَعَا اللهُ الْجَلَدَ سَمَاءً. وَكَانَ مَسَاءٌ وَكَانَ صَبَاحٌ يَوْمًا ثَانِيًا.
9 وَقَالَ اللهُ: «لِتَجْتَمِعِ الْمِيَاهُ تَحْتَ السَّمَاءِ إِلَى مَكَانٍ وَاحِدٍ، وَلْتَظْهَرِ الْيَابِسَةُ». وَكَانَ كَذلِكَ. 
10 وَدَعَا اللهُ الْيَابِسَةَ أَرْضًا، وَمُجْتَمَعَ الْمِيَاهِ دَعَاهُ بِحَارًا. وَرَأَى اللهُ ذلِكَ أَنَّهُ حَسَنٌ. "`

Just for the info:the text is in sqlite database and 
I want to show it in android text view

Comment: will the numbers always be sequential?

Comment: Yes, i want to start new line with every number

Comment: The data is one column & row in SQLite? If so, why?

Comment: It is and i need it to be like this

Comment: i'd suspect you could use Regex to find 'integer[space]' and replace it with '[line break]integer[space]' - Kotlin should understand javascript, if my limited understanding is correct.  - Im sorry I'm not good with regex...but try searching on find and replace using regex.

Comment: Your input text `my_text` looks like it is already multi-line. Is it intentional?

Comment: Yes it is, this is arabic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just split this string by regex.

One option would be to use `\\s(?=\\d+)`, which will match whitespace character followed by any number of digits. For example:

```
val str = "1 Hello world 2 how are you 3 im fine here"

val r = str.split("\\s(?=\\d+)".toRegex())

r.forEach(::println)
```

and then to create one string with newlines use `joinToString`:

```
println(r.joinToString("\n"))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a combination of @RandallFlagg's and @user3357604's answers and it does literally what was asked for, possible more efficently:

```
val text = "1 فِي الْبَدْءِ خَلَقَ اللهُ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالأَرْضَ. 2 وَكَانَتِ الأَرْضُ خَرِبَةً وَخَالِيَةً، وَعَلَى وَجْهِ الْغَمْرِ ظُلْمَةٌ، وَرُوحُ اللهِ يَرِفُّ عَلَى وَجْهِ الْمِيَاهِ. 3 وَقَالَ اللهُ: «لِيَكُنْ نُورٌ»، فَكَانَ نُورٌ. 4 وَرَأَى اللهُ النُّورَ أَنَّهُ حَسَنٌ. وَفَصَلَ اللهُ بَيْنَ النُّورِ وَالظُّلْمَةِ. 5 وَدَعَا اللهُ النُّورَ نَهَارًا، وَالظُّلْمَةُ دَعَاهَا لَيْلاً. وَكَانَ مَسَاءٌ وَكَانَ صَبَاحٌ يَوْمًا وَاحِدًا.6 وَقَالَ اللهُ: «لِيَكُنْ جَلَدٌ فِي وَسَطِ الْمِيَاهِ. وَلْيَكُنْ فَاصِلاً بَيْنَ مِيَاهٍ وَمِيَاهٍ». 7 فَعَمِلَ اللهُ الْجَلَدَ، وَفَصَلَ بَيْنَ الْمِيَاهِ الَّتِي تَحْتَ الْجَلَدِ وَالْمِيَاهِ الَّتِي فَوْقَ الْجَلَدِ. وَكَانَ كَذلِكَ. 8 وَدَعَا اللهُ الْجَلَدَ سَمَاءً. وَكَانَ مَسَاءٌ وَكَانَ صَبَاحٌ يَوْمًا ثَانِيًا.9 وَقَالَ اللهُ: «لِتَجْتَمِعِ الْمِيَاهُ تَحْتَ السَّمَاءِ إِلَى مَكَانٍ وَاحِدٍ، وَلْتَظْهَرِ الْيَابِسَةُ». وَكَانَ كَذلِكَ. 10 وَدَعَا اللهُ الْيَابِسَةَ أَرْضًا، وَمُجْتَمَعَ الْمِيَاهِ دَعَاهُ بِحَارًا. وَرَأَى اللهُ ذلِكَ أَنَّهُ حَسَنٌ. "

val res = text.replace(Regex("""(\d+)\s""")) { match -> 
    val (num) = match.destructured 
    "\n$num "
}

println(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used one kotlin method to remove whitespace with trimMargin() function and By default | is used as margin prefix.

```
        var text = """|1 Hello world
                |2 how are you
                |3 im fine here""".trimMargin()
    println(text)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this ..use '< br >' instead of '\n' if kotlin doesn't like it

example string

```
str = '1 one 2 two, two and a half, 3 three and four and five';
console.log(str); 

-- 
1 one 2 two, two and a half, 3 three and four and five
```

example solution

```
str2 = str.replace(/.(?=[0-9]\s)/gi, '\n');
console.log(str2); 

--
1 one 
2 two, two and a half, 
3 three and four and five
```

Comment: ok, whoever -1'd me for giving a workable answer, check yourself. that's rude.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, your answer is in JavaScript for some reason

Comment: I don't know if you are talking about me but your answer didn't work but thanks for the help Anyway and sorry for bothering